How to infer union type from rest property?
I would like to get union type from rest property as a generic. I want to conditionally set return type of function based on that if there is at least one element in rest property which is not string or number.
type TTranslationResult<T> = T extends number | string
  ? string
  : ReactNode | ReactNode[];

export default function translate<T extends ReactNode = string>(
  key: TDictionaryKey,
  ...params: T[]
): TTranslationResult<T> {

...

}

I would expect T to be string | ReactNode when I send something like this to the function:
translate(
   'XXX',
   'some string',
   <LinkText href={`foo`}>
       {foo}
   </LinkText>
)

Instead it infers type of the first property in the array

Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's TDictionaryKey? What's LinkText? Please [edit] your code so it's a [mre] we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.

(see prev comment). • Note that string | ReactNode is just ReactNode because ReactNode is already a union including string. • Assuming my guesses about the [mre] are correct, does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (and [edit] your question to use my guesses for the [mre]). If not, what's missing?

@jcalz as I understand LinkText is a React component.

@mrconcerned Okay, but it should be imported/defined or replaced with something so that the code is a [mre]. Right now it's just a big error in the IDE.

@jcalz sorry going to update it so you can reproduce.

I found out the solution. You have to expect T to be an array, not element of an array.
type TTranslationResult<T> = T extends (number | string)[]
  ? string
  : ReactNode | ReactNode[];

export default function translate<T extends ReactNode[] = string[]>(
  key: TDictionaryKey,
  ...params: T
): TTranslationResult<T> {
{

...

}

